# Infinite loop or "recursive" in Asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm new to Python3 asyncio.

I have a function that constantly retrieves messages from a websocket connection.

I'm wondering whether I should use a `while True` loop or `asyncio.ensure_future` in a recursive manner.

Which is preferred or does it not matter?

**Example:**

```
async def foo(websocket):
    while True:
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        print(msg)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)
```

**or**

```
async def foo(websocket):
    msg = await websocket.recv()
    print(msg)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)
    asyncio.ensure_future(foo(websocket))
```

Comment: It's ok to just `asyncio.sleep(0)` to yield the control back to the loop. No need to use `0.0001`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the iterative variant, for two reasons:

1. It is easier to understand and extend. One of the benefits of coroutines compared to callback-based futures is that they permit the use of familiar control structures like `if` and `while` to model the code's execution. If you wanted to change your code to e.g. add an outer loop around the existing one, or to add some code (e.g. another loop) after the loop, that would be considerably easier in the non-recursive version.
2. It is more efficient. Calling `asyncio.ensure_future(foo(websocket))` instantiates both a new coroutine object and a brand new task for each new iteration. While neither are particularly heavy-weight, all else being equal, it is better to avoid unnecessary allocation.